# Evaluate the complex integral$\oint\tan(z)\,dz$ around various contours C

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I can expand $\tan(z)=\dfrac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}$ . Then the poles are z = (2n+1)$\pi$/2 where n=0,-1,+1,-2,+2....

So there is an infinite number of poles and thus residues. So how do I evaluate this function?

Comment: There will  be a finite number of poles inside any contour.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you elaborate on it?